# Grouping customers together into like groups based on multiple variables without a categorical variable

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I am looking for a little guidance as to the correct approach to this problem. We have a list of IDs and roughly 8 different numerical variables such as quantity and revenue. Each ID is unique to the dataset.

We are looking to group these customers together based on the 8 different variables.

At first we looked into k-means clustering, however that only accounted for one variable and the groups were unhelpful (ie there were 2 groups with just one customer in them and then rest were all grouped together, when we tried more clusters it became even more convoluted.)

We are attempting to do this in R and were curious if anyone had any recommendations as to which approach we should take?

Also, this is not homework for a stats class, this is a real business application.

Answer (score 1):

If your variables have very different scale, you really need to normalize them before clustering. If you have highly skewed data (revenue and income usually are skewed) you may need to look into nonlinear normalizations. This will help with every clustering algorithm.

Most other clustering algorithms also require you to specify a similarity measure. Do not assume the default just works.
Spend a considerable amount of time on **how to quantify the similarity of cutomers**? Only once you are confident with your measure, you can experiment with HAC, DBSCAN, OPTICS etc.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how many clients we are talking about. For a large number of customers your choice of clustering algorithm would be limited. Try the "clara" function in the "cluster" library.

Also your two small clusters and one really large one suggests that maybe your columns are not scaled properly (see the "scale" function).

If this is relatively small dataset, you can try creating a heatmap with hierarchical clustering (see the "heatmap" function) to get around the problem of having to pre-determine the number of groups.